# Using COUNT and DISTINCT keywords together to count distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, distinct

I am writing the query to count the number of distinct values in the database table. So I wrote the query as:

`select count ( distinct user_id ) as unique_users from 1_time_access;`

I am getting error

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'distinct user_id ) as unique_users from 1_time_access' at line 1`

Can anyone explain what am I missing?

Comment: Looks OK. Make sure you have no tab characters in there

Comment: it is just the space after `distinct`. it worked now. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space between `count` and the open parenthesis.

```
select count(distinct user_id) as unique_users from 1_time_access;
```