# Find the overlap group through Inner Join for specific dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL so appreciate any help on this. I've been using an inner join and where clause to get all the unique Jedi who were active for 3 months in the Republic Area (Republic Table) and then determine how many of these Jedi were part of the Rebel Alliance (Rebel Table).

My query does execute but the data make me doubt I'm doing it right. Thank you for your help on this.

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT republic.jedi_id)
FROM republic
INNER JOIN rebel ON republic.jedi_id = rebel.jedi_id
WHERE republic.date>='2020-01-01' AND republic.date <='2020-03-31'
```

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Your query looks correct. Have you tried executing it with your data? For further troubleshooting, consider sharing your sample input data and expected output.

Comment: no @lemon the quer has a fatal flaw see my answer

Comment: I'm failing to understand what you changed wrt OP's query. The `DISTINCT` is in the exact same place of OP's. Can you provide more details? @nbk

Comment: @lemon if i may a quick question - what would happen if for where - i used rebel.date instead of rebublic. Does that give me the unique Jedi active during those specific rebel years?

Comment: @lemon `COUNT (DISTINCT` is something differently from `COUNT(DISTINCT` first prodices an erroro as you can se in mysql workbench last works just fine to be clear my answer invokes teh function COUNT the original does not

Comment: Update your post with some sample tables and expected output @Omar

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference. @nbk >> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rBzJQs6KRHnwwkriuTTB9X/0. Though can you provide some documentation? This can become a really fruitful post.

Comment: @lemon MySQL Workbench doesn't like it

Comment: It seems to be a problem of MySQL workbench. Check here >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113229/using-count-and-distinct-keywords-together-to-count-distinct-values.

Comment: @lemon just added the picture showing the table example.  if I used rebel.date instead of rebublic. Does that mean I'll see the orange only correct? And if I use the republic.date I should only see the green?

Comment: @lemon i don't see it as problem, COUNT() is a function Count () not

Comment: As long as your dates are different between your two tables, your output will change definitely. @Omar

Comment: If the OP and other people will experience that kind of issue with their query, they will find your detailed solution. @nbk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query is pretty much correct.
Distinct is needed if there are than one Jedi with same name is any of the table.

```
SELECT COUNT republic.jedi_id
FROM republic
INNER JOIN rebel ON republic.jedi_id = rebel.jedi_id
WHERE republic.date>='2020-01-01' AND republic.date <='2020-03-31'
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL interprets your code as two commands and produces an error because `DISTINCT` is at the wrong place.

To be precise:

- `COUNT(DISTINCT` invokes the Function COUNT with distinct rows
- `COUNT (DISTINCT` is treated as two separate commands and DISTINCT belongs at the beginning direct after the SELECT, which gives an error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT republic.jedi_id) FROM republic INNER JOIN rebel ON republic.jedi_id = ' at line 1

Rewrite your code to:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT republic.jedi_id)
FROM republic
INNER JOIN rebel ON republic.jedi_id = rebel.jedi_id
WHERE republic.date>='2020-01-01' AND republic.date <='2020-03-31'
```